# Rails 5.1.6 font awesome: link_to tags and span

Tags: bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5, font-awesome

The code work as intended. I am trying to change the appearance of this:

```
       <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to user_path(current_user.id) do %>
        <a <%= content_tag :span, "User", :class => "nav-link" %>
          <i class="far fa-user"></i>
        </a>
        <% end %>
      </li>
```

to invert the font awesome tag. I would like it to appear before the "User" link.

How can I achieve that ?

Thanks

Comment: I do not seem to know how to solve this.  I have improved the look w/o having booth look and link both working.  any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the issue with the following:

```
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a>
        <%= link_to user_path(current_user.id), class:"nav-link" do %>
          <i class="far fa-user"></i>
          <%= content_tag :span, "User view" %>
            <% end %>
        </a>
      </li>
```